# Eliminar números repetidos en un array

Tags: javascript, array

No puedo solucionar esta tarea, he usado otros métodos y nada. El problema en custión dice:

> La funcion 'buscaDestruye' recibe como argumento un array de enteros 'arreglo' y un entero 'num'.
>
> Esta funcion tiene que eliminar los numeros del array que coincidan con el numero recibido como argumento (num).
>
> La función debe retornar el array sin los números sacados.
> Nota: Si el numero se repite mas de una vez, tambien hay que eliminarlo.

```js
var num = [1, 2, 7, 3, 9]
array.splice(1, 1);

{
  var number = [1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 7];

  var arr = []
  var k = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < number.length; i++) {

    if (number.sort()[i] != number.sort()[i - 1]) {

      arr[k] = number.sort()[i]
      k++;
    }
  }
}
```

- `buscaDestruye([1, 2, 7, 3, 9], 2)` debería eliminar 2 de [1, 2, 7, 3, 9] y retornar [1, 7, 3, 9]
- `buscaDestruye([1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 7], 2)` debería eliminar 1 de [1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 7] y retornar [2, 4, 2, 3, 5, 7]

Comment: intente probar otras funciones como, delete, remove, destroyer y otros metodos

Comment: ¿Debes modificar el array original? Porque podrías usar solo un `for` y `.indexOf` para lograr tu cometido.

Comment: Especifica el lengiaje de programacion

Comment: javascript el lenguaje

Comment: @ricardo-dlc cual array original? o.O

Comment: @tomi.gonza, describes que debe ser una función que reciba dos parámetros, un array y el número a eliminar, `buscaDestruye(arreglo, num)`, la función ¿debe mutar el array original o es válido retornar uno completamente nuevo?

Comment: @ricardo-dlc nose cual es valido, soy nuevo en javascript y llevo una semana intentando resolver ese problema de buscadestruye

Comment: Vale, para empezar deberías de tener en cuenta que como está publicado tu código ahora mismo dará error puesto que tienes un `};` demás al final y en la segunda línea no tienes definido `array` previamente.

Comment: De igual manera te sugiero investigar acerca de los [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario utilizar métodos como `.filter()`, `.slice()`, `.sort()`, etc, puesto que el problema es bastante sencillo. Basta con recorrer el arreglo y comparar si el elemento `i` es distinto de `num`, de ser así puedes agregarlo a un arreglo auxiliar y cuando termines retornar ese arreglo con los elementos "filtrados".

```js
const buscaDestruye = (arreglo, num) => {
  const nuevoArreglo = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    if (arreglo[i] !== num) {
      nuevoArreglo.push(arreglo[i]);
    }
  }
  return nuevoArreglo;
}

console.log(buscaDestruye([1, 2, 7, 3, 9], 2));
console.log(buscaDestruye([1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 7], 1));
```

Puesto que parece ser más un problema de lógica que de conocimiento de métodos del objecto [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), pienso que no hay problema en que el código parezca un poco largo. En caso de que el problema principal sea reducir líneas de código, entonces podrías optar por la respuesta de @rene, incluso existen otras formas de lograr el mismo resultado usando otros métodos, pero creo que para eso entonces deberías entender bien qué es lo que pasa detrás de esos métodos.

Answer (score 3):

```
function buscaDestruye(arr, num){
    return arr.filter(n => n !== num);
}
```

Usa mejor esta forma en la programación funcional no debes provocar *side effects*, esta función devuelve el array sin el número.